# Turn function names (of function headers) bold in VS Code

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code

In Visual Studio Code, how can I embold the C# function name in functions (but not the function calls, only the headers)? E.g. via adjusting settings.json textMateRules entity.name.function, or any other approach. The end result should be like this, having functions serve as quasi-headlines in the code flow:

```
void Foo()
{
    int i = 0;
}

void Bar()
{
     Foo();
}
```

(The question has been marked as a duplicate of how to embolden all but comments, but that's not the same, unfortunately. I'm specifically interested how to embolden just function names, as described above.)

Comment: Please [see](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53996258/1797425) that post, specifically look at the `textMate.Rules` section.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VS Code: How to make all text bold, except the comments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53996258/vs-code-how-to-make-all-text-bold-except-the-comments); you need to modify the `textMate.Rules` section.

Comment: Sorry, but that's not a duplicate of that question, as I need something else embolded. I'm aware of how to adjust the comments/ noncomments boldness, but it's now what I'm looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I was looking for something similar for my C Development.

This is my `settings.json` file:

```
{
    "C_Cpp.default.cStandard": "c99",
    "C_Cpp.default.intelliSenseMode": "gcc-x64",
    "javascript.suggest.completeFunctionCalls": true,
    "editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
        "textMateRules": [
            {
                "scope": "meta.function",
                "settings": {
                    "fontStyle": "bold"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

And my VS Code editor has changed to like this:

[image: example screenshot]

Comment: Strange, this looks like it could work but when I try, doesn't...

Comment: whats ur settings, let me know it

Comment: Thanks, [these are my settings](https://github.com/JPhilipp/VSCodeMinimal/blob/master/settings.json). For C#.

Comment: add  "fontStyle": "bold"  in ur settings and try different themes, prefer some default ones

Comment: I had your fontStyle bold addition included -- this was the pre-inclusion of your state -- but it didn't work for some reason. Thanks though.